# Angular route throws 500 Internal server error on refresh the page when I remove the canActivate from the route

Tags: angular, routes, canactivate

I am having an angular 11 app. It throws a 500 internal server error on the route when I refresh the page. This started to happen when I remove the "**canActivate**" from the route. This only happens on **deployed environment** but not in local.

```
{
path: 'events/:EventName/speakers',
loadChildren: () =>
  import('./views/pages/speakers/speakers.module').then(
    (m) => m.SpeakersModule
  ),
resolve: [RouteResolver],
 //commented out
// canActivate: [AuthGuardForEvent],
data: { pageId: ePageIds.Speaker },},
```

[image]

Comment: Angular doesn't throw 500 errors, the API your calling is. The dev tools makes that very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is a web frontend tool, which compiles down to plain HTML, Javascript and CSS, which is then served by a server to different web browsers (clients). This means that Angular itself is not setting any HTTP status codes, because it is only served content, but not the server itself.

You should check for the logs of your actual server to find a hint on what causes this error.